# Use Nokogiri to extract the first 2 table cells in all table rows

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a table and want to use Nokogiri to extract the content of the first two cells in every table row. Currently I'm facing some difficult and want to get some help from you. This is what I get now. Any one can help me? Thanks.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'nokogiri'
=> true
irb(main):002:0>
irb(main):003:0* @doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse <<-EOHTML
irb(main):004:0" <body>
irb(main):005:0" <div class="c">
irb(main):006:0" <table>
irb(main):007:0"     <tr>
irb(main):008:0"         <td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td>
irb(main):009:0"     </tr>
irb(main):010:0"     <tr class="even">
irb(main):011:0"         <td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td>
irb(main):012:0"     </tr>
irb(main):013:0"     <tr>
irb(main):014:0"         <td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td>
irb(main):015:0"     </tr>
irb(main):016:0"     <tr class="even">
irb(main):017:0"         <td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td>
irb(main):018:0"     </tr>
irb(main):019:0" </table>
irb(main):020:0" </div>
irb(main):021:0" </body>
irb(main):022:0" EOHTML
irb(main):026:0> @doc.css("div.c > table").search("table/tr/td")
=> ...
irb(main):026:0> @doc.css("div.c > table").search("table/tr/td[position()>2]")
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '>' after '#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x2b7bc20>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:87:in `on_error'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/racc/parser.rb:99:in `_racc_do_parse_c'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/racc/parser.rb:99:in `do_parse'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:62:in `parse'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:79:in `xpath_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/css.rb:23:in `xpath_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in
css'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:109:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:109:in `block in css'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:239:in `block in each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `upto'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:105:in `css'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:83:in `block in search'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:80:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:80:in `search'
        from (irb):27
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'irb(main):028:0>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said in a comment that you'd like to preserve the logical relationship of cells within the same row:

```
@doc.css('div.c > table > tr').each do |tr|
  td1, td2 = tr.xpath('./td') # Find only direct child items
  # td1 is the first <td>, td2 the second
end
```

If you want to efficiently extract all the text at once:

```
data = @doc.css('tr').map do |row|
  # Find the text for all td, get the first two, then join with ' - '
  row.xpath('./td').map(&:text)[0,2].join(' - ')
end

puts data
#=> a1 - b1
#=> a2 - b2
#=> a3 - b3
#=> a4 - b4
```

*The above output comes from slightly more interesting test data than all "test".*

Answer (score 3):

Use an XPath query:

```
@doc.xpath('//table/tr/td[1] | //table/tr/td[2]')
```

This will return the first and second `td` nodes within a `tr` node having a `table` node as parent.

Comment: Hi Vivien, your method will treat all matched table cells the same way. In fact, the two cells in every row in my example have some relation, and I need the values of them. Are there any way that can extract them and reserve the relation of them? For example, how to get the first 2 cells in every row and concatenate them? Thanks.

Comment: @Yousui Fetch just the first `td`, and when iterating over them use [`td.next_element`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-next_element) to find the second `td` in that row.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a SAX parser

```
class ShowtimeDaily < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  attr_reader :td_count
  def start_element name, attrs =[]
  case name
  when 'tr'
    @td_count = 0
  when 'td'
    @td_count +=1
  end

 def characters string
   # string containts the content you'd be requiring
   puts "content of row number #{@td_count}: #{string}" if @td_count < 3
 end
```

The code that I've written will most probably be having errors in it as I haven't validated it. I hope it serves well in solving your problem.

Comment: I would *never* suggest using a SAX parser, unless absolutely necessary (hitting memory limits, and pull parsing is not an option). The API is horrid.